# GPIO stopped working under Python after using SPI

Tags: gpio, python, spi

I'm using a Gertboard, and the GPIO Python demos were running fine.  I started using/modifying the DAC and ADC demo code, and now I can't output to GPIO using Python (e.g. the Gertboard `leds-rg.py` doesn't flash the LEDs).

It's not a Gertboard configuration issue, because if I disconnect the Gertboard I still can't set the GPIO pins from Python (no errors, but a voltmeter doesn't change).  `gpio write` in a terminal works fine.

In Python I get a warning that the channel is already in use, continuing anyway (using a channel that doesn't have a use for SPI).

`gpio readall` doesn't show any changes I make in Python including to the pin mode, it does of course reflect changes made using `gpio mode` and `gpio write`

In order to get SPI running I had to install a few things: (python-dev, spi-dev) and I also ran `apt-get upgrade`, and of course had to turn on SPI in `raspi-config`.

It's a Model 2B running Raspbian, and I'm using Python 2. RPi.GPIO is version 0.5.11.

Comment: Which GPIO are not working?  Ones on the Pi or ones on the Gertboard?

Comment: @joan both.  I can take the Gertboard off the Pi, and the ones on the Pi board don't switch.  I can pick up the same lines on the Gertboard (with or without straps to other bits of the Gertboard and they don't switch.  I'm not trying to use the ATmega IO pins (yet).

Comment: It sounds like a transient problem.  There is no reason for wiringPi (gpio readall, mode, write) to work and not Python.  Perhaps a reboot will sort out the problem.

Comment: @joan, I wish it would - reboots are probably into double figures today as I try things like disabling autoloading the SPI drivers.

Comment: Try my [pigpio Python module](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html).

Comment: @joan, I didn't get the chance to try this last week, but it's working a treat now.  Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it? (I still wish I could get to the bottom of it, but it's more important to have it working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still don't know what the underlying issue was, the `pigpio` library provided a solution (as suggested by @joan in the comments).  Swapping the library calls from `RPi.gpio` to `pigpio` was simple enough (in code based on the Gertboard python demos).

[Apparently](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39068/36740) `device_tree=on` in `/boot/config.txt` can [cause problems with RPi.GPIO](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=10407)