# RPi.GPIO not working

Tags: raspbian, python, rpi.gpio

I was trying to light an LED using RPi.GPIO on my Raspberry Pi 2 and it's not working. I'm able to do the same using pi4j library in Java. Following is the Java code which I have used to light LED.

```
final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
final GpioPinDigitalOutput pin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, "MyLED", PinState.LOW);
pin.setShutdownOptions(true, PinState.LOW);

pin.high();
Thread.sleep(1000);
pin.low();

gpio.shutdown();
```

And my python code using RPi.GPIO is,

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

pin = 12

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup(pin)
```

What might be the reason for this issue? Since pi4j is working I think no issues with my Raspberry Pi. I'm a newbie to Raspberry Pi, any help will be appreciated.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Usually the problem is the numbering scheme in use.  Pin 18 is GPIO 24.  Is that the GPIO being used for your LED?

Comment: @joan: I've used GPIO 24 too, no luck. I have connected my LED's +ve to GPIO_GEN1/GPIO 18/PIN 12. and -ve to PIN 6.

Comment: Pin 12 is GPIO18.  In your RPi.GPIO code you are using BOARD numbering.  Which means by pin.  So use 12 in that RPi.GPIO code.

Comment: I've tried 12/BOARD and 18/BCM and different pins using both BOARD and BCM numbering. Nothing seems to be working. :(

Comment: According to http://pi4j.com/pins/model-b-plus.html Pi4J number 1 is pin 12.  Pin 12 is actually connected to GPIO 18.  As far as RPi.GPIO is concerned that is 12 if BOARD numbering is being used and 18 if Broadcom numbering is used.  Which model Pi are you using?

Comment: I'm using http://pi4j.com/pins/model-2b-rev1.html (Raspberry Pi 2). I tried both 12/BOARD and 18/BCM. It didn't work.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  Perhaps post a photo of your set up?  However if the Pi4J code works I'd expect the RPi.GPIO code to work.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you make any wiring changes? Could you have reversed the LED polarity between the working code run and the non working code?

Comment: @Joan : I've updated the question with picture.

Comment: @SteveRobillard : When I reversed the LED polarity even working java code stopped working. And still no luck with python code. :(

Comment: I can't see a resistor.  You might have blown the LED and there is a remote chance you may have damaged the GPIO.  Does it still work with Pi4J?

Comment: It always worked with pi4j. Thanks for the info, I'll add a resistor. But I think that's not the reason behind this issue. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting `device_tree=on` fixed my issues with `RPi.GPIO`library.Issue explained [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=104076).

Comment: This might just be the anser to [my question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38583/36740) as well.  I added `device_tree=on` to get SPI working.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add "device_tree=on" to your /boot/config.txt file. It will prevent your pi to boot. Bad answer. This statement is WRT Raspberry Pi 2

Comment: Would you care to elaborate a bit on this answer? As it it now, it is a little bit hard to understand.